# Was my C file generated from Pro*C

Tags: c++, sql, c

We are in the process of inhereting an application from another developer. To support it properly we are first auditing what's working and what's missing in the application, and if all the fonts compile to the matching binaries.

During this process, we found a C file, which to my little knowledge in the subject, seems to have been generated from a Pro*C file.

When confronted, the previous developer says it is NOT generated from a Pro*C and that he just modifies it in Visual Studio (Odd). It seems close to imposible to maintain such a file as it is. Let me show you some things in it:

```
/* CUD (Compilation Unit Data) Array */
static short sqlcud0[] =
{12,4130,31,0,0,
5,0,0,0,0,0,27,980,0,0,4,4,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,1,10,0,0,1,10,0,0,1,10,0,0,
36,0,0,2,60,0,4,984,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2,3,0,0,
55,0,0,3,74,0,2,1000,0,0,3,3,0,1,0,1,3,0,0,1,3,0,0,1,3,0,0,
82,0,0,4,0,0,29,1077,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
```

This array goes on for over 17 thousand characters.

Or even:

```
static struct sqlcxp sqlfpn =
{
    10,
    "nameoftheCfile.pc"
};
```

So, I was wondering, is it possible that he is really using some Visual Studio tool to generate this C file, and it's not really a Pro*C?
Is it possible that Visual Studio or other tool generates this file, and he is unaware that it comes from a Pro*C file?
Is it possible to confirm a 100% that this is actually a compiled Pro*C file?

I'm hoping this is just a misunderstanding with the previous developer and not that he is refusing to give us the original fonts...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google Pro*C and copy pasta parts of your code, and you get very similar blobs of magic numbers. Of course this is auto-generated, I would be _very_ concerned if a human wrote ugly code like that. Perhaps it originates from Pro*C and is maintained manually? However, I don't know these tools so I'll refrain from posting an answer.

Comment: I suspect that you might be getting a "programmer's answer" - the file *in its current state* wasn't generated by Pro*C since it's been edited by hand. (Some programmers will provide an answer to what you say rather than to what you mean.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was generated by Pro*C. sqlcud or CUD (Compilation Unit Data) Array, is generated by Pro*C, but it´s structure was not revealed by Oracle.

Also, we found an old manual in the developers site where it proudly stated that Pro*C was used to create the software.

Thanks everyone.